# Show full rosparam filepath

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running a node with roslaunch and loading filepaths into the rosparam server, the terminal output clips the end of the filepath as shown:

```
PARAMETERS
* /driver/transforms_path: /home/matt/rosdat...
* /driver/alg_settings_path: /home/matt/rosdat...
* /driver/settings_dir: /home/matt/rosdat...
* /rosdistro: kinetic 
* /rosversion: 1.12.14
```

How do I force ROS to show the full, unclipped filepath? Seeing the full path makes debugging faster and easier.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345644/show-full-rosparam-filepath/) by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2327 on 2020-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't, as it isn't supported.

The code which prints the *summary* (as that's what it's called), is [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/8c0d9bc5e13bce5b064e316867b6f14da0b90d02/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/config.py#L225-L273). Notice how `max_length` is hard-coded to `20`.

You could consider proposing a PR (similar to [ros/ros_comm#1655](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1655)) which adds a command line option for this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2020-03-02**:
Ah, I was afraid that might be the answer. Thanks a lot!